# No logro conectar mi API a la base de datos alojada en Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Cuando hago una petición a la base de datos que tengo alojada en Heroku, (sí tengo mis credenciales perfectamente escritas en Pool), me sale el siguiente error:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "xxxxxxx", database "xxxxxxxx", SSL off
```

Estoy usando Node Express Y postgresql.

Comment: Es un tema de configuración, debes agregar tu IP al archivo `pg_hba.conf` de tu servidor

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo ok, y cómo lo agrego? cómo lo escribo? ni idea de que existía ese archivo

Answer (score 2):

Ese archivo debe estar en tu servidor, búscalo en el directorio de datos de PostgreSQL, o puedes hacer la siguiente consulta y te dice donde está:

```
select name, setting FROM pg_settings where name='hba_file';
```

debes agregar una linea como esta al archivo

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    tubase          tuusuario       tu_ip/32                md5
```

y hacerle un reload a la configuración de PostgreSQL:

```
systemctl reload postgresql
```

o ejecutar la consulta:

```
postgres=# select pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf 
----------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Esto lo tengo que hacer en el archivo pg_hba.conf de mi sistema? o accedo la configuración de heroku desde la terminal? de la primera forma no me funciona, sigue dandome el mismo error, y de la segunda forma, me dice acceso negado. no entiendo

Comment: vas a tener que ver con el soporte de heroku entonces para que te dejen modificar eso: puedes mirar acá: https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres